# how to redirect pages based on language using JavaScript language window.location

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to add multi language button to my site in the form of a select tag with options for each language which redirects to the home pages for each language.

However, this seems to work only on **PC Browsers** and not **on Mobile** browsers.

what is the problem?

Here is the my code:

```
 <!--Changing language client side-->
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

function Redirect_en(){
  window.location="index.html";
 } 

function Redirect_fr(){
 window.location="fr/fr-index.html";
} 

function Redirect_es(){
  window.location="es/es-index.html";
} 

function Redirect_zh(){
   window.location="zh/zh-index.html";
} 

</script>
 .
...
      <span id="lang_header_form"> 
       <form  method="POST" id="lang_form">             
           <select name="language" id="lang_select">
              <option value ="English" onclick="Redirect_en();"         selected>English</option>
              <option value = "French" onclick="Redirect_fr();">French</option>
              <option value="Spanish" onclick="Redirect_es();">Spanish</option>
              <option value="Chinese"    onclick="Redirect_zh();">Chinese</option>
          </select>
       </form>
    </span>
```

Comment: What actually does happen on the mobile browsers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, have a look at [ask] and clarify your question a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="Lang" onchange="changeLang(this)">
 <option value="en">English</option>
 <option value="fr">French</option>
</select>
<script>
   function changeLang(selectObject) {
     switch(selectObject.value){
        case 'en': window.location="/index.html"; break;
        case 'fr': window.location="fr/fr-index.html"; break;
      }
   }
</script>
```

The above example gets you the selected language on OnChange event. which should work in mobile

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function redirect(self){
  window.location = self.value + 'index.html';
}
```

```html
<select name="language" onchange="redirect(this);">
    <option value="" selected>English</option>
    <option value="fr/fr-">French</option>
    <option value="es/es-">Spanish</option>
    <option value="zh/zh-">Chinese</option>
</select>
```